# $f\left( x+\frac{1}{x} \right)=\frac{x+x^3}{1+x^4}$ find $f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a good way to solve this problem simply?
I set $t=x+\frac{1}{x}$ but this will make the equation very complicated.
$$f\left( x+\frac{1}{x} \right)=\frac{x+x^3}{1+x^4}$$ find $f(x)$

Comment: Do you know what Linear Algebra is? If you do, why did you use the tag for this question? If you don't, why did you use the tag for this question?

Comment: Try to make $x+\frac1x$ appear on the right side of the equation; for example, by dividing the numerator and denominator by $x^2$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x+x^3}{1+x^4} = \frac{x^2(\frac{1}{x}+x)}{(1+x^2)^2-2x^2} = \frac{(\frac{1}{x}+x)}{\frac{{(1+x^2)^2-2x^2}}{x^2}} = \frac{(\frac{1}{x}+x)}{(\frac{1}{x}+x)^2-2}$$

I think the rest is obvious.